# Expressing the subscript that produces the largest element in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If I have a set $D=\{ d_1, d_2, ..., d_n \}$, and I wish to find $k\, (\leq n)$, where $d_k$ is the largest element in $D$, is it understandable that I write

$$
k = \arg\max_i \big( \big\{ d_i | d_i \in D \big\} \big)
$$

, or is there a more rigorous / acceptable / simpler way of expression?

Comment: Note that sets are not considered to be ordered, so the idea of the $k$-th element does not make sense.  You should be talking of sequences and using parentheses instead of braces.  Then the $k$-th element does make sense and so does your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I should have said $d_k$ instead of “the $k$-th element”.

Comment: The sets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{3,2,1\}$ are the same.  It makes sense to ask for the maximum element of a set, which is $3$ here.  It does not make sense to ask for its position in the set, which is what you are looking for.  For that to make sense you need something that has an order, like a sequence, array, or tuple.

Comment: @RossMillikan If $d_i$ are predefined constants (e.g. $d_1=3, d_2=1, d_3=2$), such that the $i$s are 'intrinsic' to the elements, can I say the set is orderless? I can mix the elements of $D$ without losing any information. I also need the expression that correlates with $k=1$, not $\max d_i = 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is understandable. If you want to make it explicit that $n$ is the largest index you are considering, you could write
$$k = \text{argmax}_i \{d_i | 1 \leq i \leq n\}.$$
As noted in a now-deleted comment, it is perfectly rigorous to say something like "let $k$ be such that $d_k$ is the largest element of $D$" which is both rigorous and more readable in a proof.

Comment: Thank you. @MJD also raised the problem where there may be multiple $k$s when $d_k$ is the value for more than 1 element in the set $D$. How should I reflect this in the argmax notation?

Comment: In that case the argmax is not a unique value but rather a set of values. If you don't care which is selected, you could say $k \in \text{argmax}_i\{d_i | 1 \leq i \leq n\}$. In the case where the max is unique, then the argmax is a singleton set.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little confusing.  Sets don't normally have an order, so it's not clear what the subscripts mean.   If you want the number that is the largest element of $D$ then $$\max D$$ is the simplest way to write it.

If $D$ is actually a *sequence*, rather than a set, then the subscripts do make sense.  But now you have the possible confusion that there might be more than one largest element.  If $D = \langle 1, 4, 2, 4, 4\rangle$ are you looking for $i=2, i=4$, or $i=5$?

Supposing that you don't care which subscript you get, as long as it identifies one maximum element, probably the simplest thing to say is:

> Let $k$ be such that $d_k = \max D$.

This is simple, clear, and also 100% rigorous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To me $i$ matters much more than $d_i$ (I'm doing a cluster analysis on experimental data; $i$ are the cluster numbering and $d_i$ are the probability densities of a specific point to each of these Gaussian clusters. I need to know which cluster the point is closest to, which translates to finding $k$ where $d_k$ is the largest among all probability densities.)